# Responsive topnav not working

Tags: jquery, css, navigation

I'm having a problem with a responsive navbar tutorial I'm trying on my website ( here it is:
[CodePen](http://codepen.io/chorijan/pen/aqDpo) ).
I've copied everything in my html/css and added the js in a  tag but when I resize the window, it won't close the navbar and show the 'open' button like on the Codepen, it just stacks all menu items vertically and I can only click on 'Home'.
Can you help me ? I hope you won't need a JsFiddle to help me cause my homepage is very complicated and copying here would be a pain in the a**.

**EDIT**: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/t8uqzo20/)
Alright I'm putting the code here but the way we have to do is boring in my opinion and a waste of time when we could just put it between two tags couldn't we?

```
<nav class="nav-collapse" role="navigation">
 <ul class="tabs primary-nav">
    <li class="tabs__item">
        <a href="#" class="tabs__link">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tabs__item">
        <a href="#" class="tabs__link">Talks</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tabs__item">
        <a href="#" class="tabs__link">Schedule</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tabs__item">
        <a href="#" class="tabs__link">Location</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tabs__item">
        <a href="#" class="tabs__link">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
 <script>
 var navigation = responsiveNav(".nav-collapse", {
 animate: true,                   
 transition: 284,                  
 label: "Menu",                    
 insert: "before",                 
 customToggle: "",                
 closeOnNavClick: false,           
  openPos: "relative",             
  navClass: "nav-collapse",         
  navActiveClass: "js-nav-active",  
  jsClass: "js",                    
  init: function(){},               // Function: Init callback
   open: function(){},               // Function: Open callback
   close: function(){}               // Function: Close callback
  });
  </script>

   </nav>

  <script>
 var lastScroll = 0;
      $(window).scroll(function(event){
          //Sets the current scroll position
          var st = $(this).scrollTop();
          //Determines up-or-down scrolling
          if (st > lastScroll){
 //scrollbtn disappears when scrolled down
            $(".scrollbtn").fadeOut();
          } 
          else {
 //secondaryNav disappears when scrolled up
           $(".scrollbtn").css ("display","block");
          }
          //Updates scroll position
          lastScroll = st;
      });</script>
 <div class="parallax">

 <div class="messwrapper">

 <div class="message" style="display:none">
 <a class="animated fadeInUp"><center>Lorem 
 <span  class="hot">ipsum</span> whatever
 <span class="hot"message</span></center></a>
 </div>

 <div class="message2" style="display:none">
 <center><a class="animated fadeInUp">
 Ipsum<span class="hot">Lorem</span>  message</a></center>
 </div>

  </div>
  <script>
  setTimeout(function () {
   $('.message').show().addClass('animated fadeInDown');}, 1000);
   setTimeout(function () {
    $('.message2').show().addClass('animated fadeInLeft');}, 4000);

    setTimeout(function () {
    $('.wbdesign').show().addClass('animated fadeInUp');}, 7000);
   setTimeout(function () {
    $('.facebk').show().addClass('animated fadeInUp');}, 8000);
   setTimeout(function () {
    $('.advert').show().addClass('animated fadeInUp');}, 9000);
    setTimeout(function () {
    $('.identity').show().addClass('animated fadeInUp');}, 10000);
    setTimeout(function () {
    $('.strat').show().addClass('animated fadeInUp');}, 11000);
    setTimeout(function () {
    $('.more').show().addClass('animated fadeInUp');}, 12000);



    </script>
    <div class="iconswrapper">

    <div class="wbdesign" style="display:none">
    <img  src="images/wbdesign.png" style="width:50%" 
    class="animated  fadeInUp" /></div>
    <div class="facebk" style="display:none">
    <img src="images/Facebook.png"  
    style="width:50%" class="animated fadeInUp" /></div>
    <div class="advert" style="display:none">
    <img src="images/Advert.png"         style="width:50%" 
     class="animated  fadeInUp" /></div>
    <div class="identity" style="display:none">
    <img  src="images/identity.png" style="width:50%" 
    class="animated fadeInUp" /></div>
    <div class="strat" style="display:none">
    <img src="images/strat.png"  style="width:50%" 
       class="animated fadeInUp" /></div>
    <div class="more" style="display:none">
    <img src="images/MORE.png"     style="width:50%" 
    class="animated fadeInUp" /></div>
     </div>

     </div>


    <div class="parallax2">
   <div class="pix">
  <img src="Images/cHOC.png" style="height:50%;">
   </div>
      </div>

     <div class="parallax3">
     <div class="bgbox">
      <div class="box2"> 
      <div class="medias">
     <div class="pic1"><div class="pic4">
     <img src="Images/Iconmail.png"  style="width:100%;"></div>
     <script>
     $('.pic1')
     .mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('animated pulse');})
        .mouseout(function(){
       $(this).removeClass('animated pulse');});
        $('.pic2')
          .mouseover(function() {
         $(this).addClass('animated pulse');})
           .mouseout(function(){
          $(this).removeClass('animated pulse');});

    $('.pic3')
      .mouseover(function() {
       $(this).addClass('animated pulse');})
         .mouseout(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('animated pulse');});

   $('.pic4')
     .mouseover(function() {
         $(this).addClass('animated pulse');})
       .mouseout(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('animated pulse');});

    </script></div>
</p>


 </p> 

  </p>

   </div>
    </div>
     <div id="footer">© 2017 "FIVE STARS .COM" All Rights Reserved</div>

            </div>
```

Comment: We need a working demo reproducing the actual problem. Without that, we're just taking shots in the dark. And including your code in the post would be best, since links to 3rd party sites (yours, codepen, jsfiddle) aren't guaranteed to work 5 years from now when someone googles this problem, finds your SO post, and tries to look at the code and can't find it because the link to a 3rd party site doesn't work.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: why can't you use bootstrap navigation bar?

Comment: First because I dont really understand what Bootstrap is yet but also because I started this and would like to understand what the problem is before going on to something else